# Benutzung des bestimmten und unbestimmten Artikels und des Nullartikels?

Tags: grammaticality

Können Sie mir bitte erklären, wann man in Deutsch den bestimmten, unbestimmten und Nullartikel benutzt?

Ich verstehe zum Beispiel nicht, warum man manchmal das Geld mit einem bestimmten Artikel schreibt und manchmal ohne.

Comment: Das ist eine sehr breitgefasste Frage. Sie könnten ein-zwei Beispiele geben, wo Sie sich mit der Verwendung des Artikels im Unklaren sind.

Comment: Ok. Ich verstehe nicht zum Beispiel warum schreibt man manchmal das Geld mit dem bestimmten Artikel und manchmal ohne ihn.

Comment: Wo finde ich nähere Informationen zu dieser Problematik bitte?

Comment: Welche ist deine Muttersprache? Hat man dort keine Artikel?

Comment: Bitte editi.ere Deine Frage, anstatt Kommentare zu schreiben. Nicht alle Kommtenare werden automatisch angezeigt. Es ist einfacher, wenn Deine Frage alle wesentlichen Informationen enthält

Comment: Meine Muttersprache ist Tschechisch und es braucht keine Artikel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das liebe Geld ist nicht abzählbar – klingt komisch, ist aber so – und daher kann man **nicht** *ein Geld* sagen:

> Ich kriege noch Geld von dir.

Ein bestimmter Artikel (»kleines Demonstrativpronomen«) geht natürlich immer:

> **Das** Geld habe ich dir doch aber schon gegeben.

---

Außer in folgendem Fall:

> Dieser Urlaub hat **ein** Geld gekostet.

Hier bedeutet *ein* dasselbe wie **unerwartet viel**.

Mit anderen nicht abzählbaren Worten ist es genauso:

> Das war **eine** Arbeit.

Comment: Häufiger wäre, meine ich, jedoch in deinem Sonderfall eine unterstreichende Wortzusammensetzung: *ein Heidengeld*, *eine Heidenarbeit*. - "Der Urlaub hat *ein Schweinegeld* gekostet."

Comment: Was "*eine Arbeit*" angeht, so ist "*die Arbeit*" nicht unbedingt nicht abzählbar: "*Der Handwerker hat zwei Arbeiten am Dach und eine an der Mauer ausgeführt.*" Ich selbst würde "*eine Arbeit*" in diesem Zusammenhang ("*Das war eine Arbeit!*") eher als abzählbares Wort sehen.

Answer (score 4):

Die Grundregel ist: Man verwendet den bestimmten Artikel, wo man in der jeweiligen Kommunikationssituation davon ausgeht, dass der Zuhörer den Gegenstand, um den es geht, schon kennt.

> Gib mir bitte Geld!

Hier ist von *irgend* einem Geld die Rede, das bisher noch nicht erwähnt war. Dagegen:

> Gibt mir bitte das Geld!

Hier ist von Geld die Rede, bei dem der Sprecher davon ausgeht, dass der Adressat (der Zuhörer) bereits weiß, von was die Rede ist. Zum Beispiel könnte der Geldbeutel ganz offen auf dem Tisch liegen, und A sagt zu B: "Gib mir bitte mal das Geld." Oder aber B schuldet A einen Betrag, und beide wissen davon (logischerweise), dann würde A sagen "Gib mir bitte das Geld zurück."

Mit "ein" (unbestimmter Artikel) kann man mit Geld leider schlecht ein Beispiel machen, da Geld im Deutschen ein per se mengenloser (nicht zählbarer) Begriff ist (wie Milch und Liebe). Darum hier ein anderes Beispiel:

> Gib mir bitte mal eine Scheibe Brot!

Irgend eine Scheibe, egal welche; eine Scheibe Brot, die bisher noch nicht erwähnt war.

> Gib mir bitte mal die Scheibe Brot!

Hier ist den Teilnehmern des Gesprächs schon klar, um welche konkrete Scheibe Brot es geht. Vielleicht wurde vorher schon drüber gesprochen, oder es ist nur noch eine einzige Scheibe da.

Answer (score 3):

Die Artikel gehören zu den [Determinativen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)). Das sind Wörter, die Substantive begleiten. Sie grenzen diese Substantive näher ein. Eine deutsche Bezeichnung könnte »Bestimmer« sein, allerdings wird dieser Begriff nicht verwendet. Der Begriff »Artikelwort« nimmt schon vorweg, welche Wörter die wichtigsten Vertreter dieser Wortart sind, nämlich die Artikel.

Andere Determinative sind meist Pronomen (**dieses** Haus, **mein** Haus), Fragewörter (**welches** Haus) oder Quantifikatoren (**kein** Haus, **drei** Häuser).

---

### Bestimmte Artikel

Das sind die bestimmten Artikel der deutschen Sprache:

> der, die, das, des, dem, den

**definit**
Einen bestimmten Artikel verwendet man, wenn ein bereits bekanntes oder nach der Beschreibung eindeutig bestimmbares Individuum wieder erwähnt wird:

> 1. Kannst du mir bitte **den** Hammer geben?
> 2. Erwin steig in **das** Auto und fuhr weg.

In (1) ist allen Beteiligen klar, welcher Hammer gemeint ist. Es ist nicht irgend ein Hammer, sondern ein ganz bestimmter. (Z.B. Der Hammer mit dem gelben Griff und der Scharte im Stiel, der in der Werkzeugkiste unter der Kneifzange liegt.)

Ebenso ist in (2) ist allen Beteiligten klar, welches Auto gemeint ist. Auch dieses Auto ist nicht irgendeines, das gerade irgendwo herumsteht, sonder ein ganz bestimmtes Exemplar. (Z.B. der dunkelgraue Skoda, den Erwin kurz vor dem Bankraub, den er soeben verübt hat, zwei Straßen weiter aufgebrochen und gestohlen hat, und den er jetzt als Fluchtfahrzeug benutzt.)

**spezifisch**
Der bestimmte Artikel wird auch verwendet, um ein Exemplar zu bezeichnen, dass bisher noch nicht erwähnt wurde, auf dessen Existenz aber alle Gesprächspartner aus dem Kontext eindeutig schließen können:

> Helga war auf dem Weg ins Krankenhaus, denn **das** Baby wollte geboren werden.
>   **Die** Torte, die Leon und Lisa für ihre Mutter backen wollten, sollte viel Schokolade enthalten.

**generisch**
Es ist aber auch möglich, einen bestimmten Artikel als generische Referenz auf alle Exemplare einer Klasse zu verwenden:

> **Der** Ackerschachtelhalm treibt seine Wurzeln bis zu 160 cm tief in den Boden.

In allen Fällen ist auch die Verwendung in der Mehrzahl möglich:

> Die Räuber stiegen in **die** Autos und fuhren weg.
>   **Die** Torten, die die Kinder backen wollten, sollten verschiedene Farben haben.
>   **Die** Ackerschachtelhalme haben quirlig verzweigte Triebe.

---

### Unbestimmte Artikel

Das sind die unbestimmten Artikel der deutschen Sprache:

> ein, eine, einer, eines, einem, einen

Alle sechs unbestimmten Artikel existieren auch als Zahlwörter, um ein einzelnes Ding zu bezeichnen. Genau aus diesen Einzahl-Wörter sind die unbestimmten Artikel auch entstanden. Sehr oft ist es auch nicht ohne weiters möglich zu entscheiden, ob so ein Wort in einem Satz gerade die Funktion eines Artikels oder eines Zahlwortes hat:

> 1. Als es läutete, habe ich mit dem Briefträger gerechnet. Ich öffnete die Tür. Dort stand **ein** Kind. Es sah mich mit großen Augen an.
> 2. Vor dem Haus hörte ich die Stimmen von drei Kindern. Ich öffnete die Tür. Dort stand **ein** Kind. Die beiden anderen rannten weg.

In (1) liegt der Fokus eher auf der Tatsache, dass die Person vor der Tür jemand war, mit dem der Sprecher nicht gerechnet hat. Hier wird »ein« also als Referenz auf ein noch nicht näher bestimmtes Exemplar einer Klasse verwendet. Es könnte jedes beliebige Kind gemeint sein. Die Tatsache, dass es nicht mehr Kinder waren, ist hier nicht so relevant. Das Wort »ein« hat hier also die Funktion eines Artikels.

In (2) geht es aber ganz genau um die Anzahl der Kinder: Es sind nicht zwei oder drei Kinder, sondern genau eines. Hier ist »ein« also ein Zahlwort.

Grundsätzlich ist zu sagen, dass unbestimmte Artikel im Deutschen ausschließlich in der Einzahl verwendet werden können, und sie bezeichnen immer ein nicht näher bestimmtes Exemplar aus einer Klasse:

**indefinit**

> Auf dem Dach des blauen Hauses wächst **ein** Baum.

Der Baum an sich ist nichts besonderes. Jeder andere Baum an dieser Stelle wäre genau so auffällig. Das Besondere ist, dass einer von den vielen Milliarden Bäumen, die es gibt, genau dort wächst. Der Baum selbst ist austauschbar, daher ist er nicht näher bestimmt, und wird mit einem unbestimmten Artikel verwendet.

**generisch**
Generische Artikel können sowohl bestimmt (siehe oben) als auch unbestimmt sein:

> Hast du schon mal **ein** Einhorn gesehen?

Auch hier tut es jedes beliebige Einhorn. Es ist ganz egal welches.

---

### Nullartikel

Mit dem Wort »Nullartikel« bezeichnet man ein Wort, das aus null Buchstaben besteht, und an einer Stelle steht, wo man eigentlich einen Artikel (genauer: ein Determinativ) erwarten würde. Der Nullartikel ist also eine besondere Art darüber zu reden, dass ein erwarteter Artikel nicht da ist.

**Plural des unbestimmten Artikels**
Der oben behandelte unbestimmte Artikel kann, aufgrund seiner Verwandtschaft mit dem Zahlwort *»eins«* nur in der Einzahl verwendet werden. Will man die Unbestimmtheit beim Wechsel in die Mehrzahl erhalten, muss man den Artikel weglassen (also den Nullartikel verwenden)

Ich hebe den Nullartikel hier mit dem Symbol »**~**« hervor. In Wahrheit steht an dieser Stelle natürlich gar nichts:

> Ich öffnete die Tür. Dort standen **~** Kinder.
>   Auf dem Dach des blauen Hauses wachsen **~** Bäume.
>   Hast du schon mal **~** Einhörner gesehen?

**unbestimmter Artikel eines Singularetantums**
Ein Singularetantum ist ein Wort, das nur im Singular vorkommt, also ein Wort, von dem man keine Mehrzahlform bilden kann. Das sind meist auch Wörter, die etwas bezeichnen, das man nicht zählen kann (Lärm, Schnee, Durst, Gesundheit, Wasser).

Diese Wörter kann man mit einem bestimmten Artikel verwenden, ganz genau so wie oben beschrieben:

> **Das** Wasser in diesem Brunnen ist vergiftet.

Manchmal möchte man solche Wörter aber auch in einem Kontext verwenden, wo man eigentlich einen unbestimmten Artikel verwenden müsste:

> Hast du schon mal *<del>ein</del>* Wasser getrunken?

Wasser kann man nicht abzählen. Man kann nicht zwei oder drei Wasser trinken, also auch nicht eines. Auch hier wirkt sich die Abstammung des unbestimmten Artikels von einem Zahlwort voll aus. Daher lässt man den Artikel weg:

> Hast du schon mal **~** Wasser getrunken?

Das gilt aber nicht nur für Dinge, die man nicht zählen kann. Das gilt auch für Singlularetantums, die Dinge bezeichnen, die man sehr wohl zählen kann, und dazu zählen z.B. *Obst* und *Geld*:

> 1. Dafür brauche ich **~** Geld.
> 2. Dafür brauche ich **einen** Kredit.

Die beiden Sätze sagen etwas ähnliches aus. In (1) wird das Singularetantum *Geld* mit einem Nullartikel verwendet, in (2) steht an derselben Stelle ein Wort, zu dem es einen Plural gibt (der Kredit, die Kredite), und daher kann der unbestimmte Artikel *einen* verwendet werden.

---

Nachsatz zu den Singularetantums:

Zu vielen dieser Wörter gibt es durchaus auch Mehrzahlformen (Wässer, Gelder), aber damit geht eine Verschiebung der Bedeutung einher. Mit *Wässern, Sanden, Milchen* usw. sind Wasserarten, Sandarten, Milcharten usw. gemeint. Damit ist also nicht mehr die Bezeichnung der generischen Gesamtheit gemeint. Streng genommen sind das andere Wörter (Homonyme).

Bei den Geldern ist das ähnlich. Mit *»Gelder«* bezeichnet man nicht den Plural des Zahlungsmittels, sondern verschiedene Geldbeträge, die aus unterschiedlichen Quellen stammen.

> Die Gelder, mit denen wir unsere Kampagne finanziert haben, stammen ausschließlich von privaten Spendern.