# Definite article in the example sentence

Tags: article

Is the following sentence correct and do we need a definite article before *"Lösung"* in it:

> Die Bevölkerung traut der Regierung Lösung aller Probleme zu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is wrong, a definite article before *»Lösung«* is missing. This is the correct sentence:

> Die Bevölkerung traut der Regierung **die** Lösung aller Probleme zu.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please elaborate in which scenarios the definite article is left out?

Comment: @D_Lernender: Leaving out a definite article means to replace it by a null article. So, it ceases being definite if you leave it out. For details see https://german.stackexchange.com/a/40061/1487 (written in German language). For English answers search for "null article".

Comment: The **indefinite** article is also possible (at least in quite similar examples, e. g. *eine Lösung für die Rentenfinanzierung*), especially since there may exist more than one solution. In plural the absence of  an article is legal (as written in the linked answer).

Comment: @guidot: But it is not »Lösung *für die Rentenfinanzierung*«. It's »Lösung *aller Probleme*«. And *»Die Bevölkerung traut der Regierung **eine** Lösung aller Probleme zu.«* does not work. This works: *»Die Bevölkerung traut der Regierung eine Lösung **für alle** Probleme zu.«* But this was not topic of the question.

Comment: Another situation where definite articles are left out is in so-called *Telegrammstil*, for example in newspaper headlines: "Bevölkerung traut Regierung Lösung aller Probleme zu."